# How do I type hiragana on Microsoft Word using the roman alphabet on my keyboard (it types a hiragana symbol per key instead!)

Tags: discussion

I'm having a bit of a hard time trying to type hiragana on Windowns. Japanese language is instaled and the IME option is on- I have actually been using it recently, but I must have pressed some key and now I get one hiragana symbol per key I press.

**If I type 'K', it will write 'の' whereas what I want is to type 'N' + 'O' to get 'の'.**

I guess this is the way some Japanese keyboards work, but I have no clue how to change it back to how it was!

Can anybody help me this this, please?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about technology

Comment: This should be asked at http://superuser.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You need to choose romaji input, not kana input.